# Sequential character substitution in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have the example makefile below. I am trying to create a directory structure with multiple substitutions, and it seems to be doing a cartesian product when I want by-index substitution:

```
genomes = C57B6NJ AKJ
GENOME_DIRS = ${genomes:%=${BASE_DATA_DIR}/genomes/%}
TWO_BITS = ${genomes:%=${GENOME_DIRS}/%.2bit}


all: 
    @echo ${TWO_BITS}


# OUTPUT
# Thu Apr 30 16:35 ~ $make all
# /genomes/C57B6NJ /genomes/AKJ/C57B6NJ.2bit /genomes/C57B6NJ /genomes/AKJ/AKJ.2bit
```

But the output I desire is

```
/genomes/C57B6NJ/C57B6NJ.2bit /genomes/AKJ/AKJ.2bit
```

How can I get this kind of positional substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second substitution is asking make to replace each word in `genomes` with the entire contents of `GENOME_DIRS` followed by the original word followed by the string `.2bit` which seems to be exactly what it is doing.

You appear to want to be adding `.2bit` to the end of the values in `GENOME_DIRS` in which case you should just do that.

Either with:

```
TWO_BITS = $(GENOME_DIRS:%=%.2bit)
```

or with:

```
TWO_BITS = $(addsuffix .2bit,$(GENOME_DIRS))
```